# Subtle WP7 Pivot ListViewItem Animation

Tags: c#, user-interface, animation, windows-phone-7, pivot

Does anyone have some WP7 code for the animations within the ListItem descriptions that animate for each ListItem when using the Pivot control (there is an example within the default WP7 settings app)?  You will see as you flick between each pivot there is a subtle animation on each description that describes what the setting does.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are refering to the system item on the SETTINGS page. 
WHen you move to that item

You could create a storyboard to animate the movement of the textblock based on teh `SelectionChanged` event and then looking at which item is selected based on `SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems`.

The animation in the settings app alters based on which direction you swipe in to get to the item. Unfortunately there's no property to tell you this.
However, if you had more than 3 items in your pivot you could work out which direction you'd swiped based on the previously selected item. If you only had 2 items in your pivot you'd need to also track Manipulation events to try and determine this.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the settings pivot item on the settings page.  I have more than two pivot items so I guess determining the direction would be easy.  Any example on an storyboard?  I haven't really used them much.

Comment: @Luke I would recommend doing animations in Expressions Blend, which makes it heaps easier to create storyboards; the WP7 training course might also have some introductory stuff around storyboards (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse_hellophonewp7lab_topic3.aspx roughly halfway down) - a quick google should bring up anything else specific you need to know about storyboards :)